# How to automate publishing .NET web applications

Tags: visual-studio, publishing, automated-deploy

There is a Visual Studio solution that has multiple web application projects. All of them are to be published to a common folder - `D:\inetpub\wwwroot\FirstSite`.
Each project has a publish profile `Local.pubxml` which imports settings from a global `publishsettings.xml`, and I use the `One-Click Publish` feature to publish each project.

Now, I would like to automate this process, which will Rebuild the solution and on success, publish all the projects to the target folder.

I have managed to create a Console application using C#, which can build all the projects in a solution. But, unfortunately could only go that far, as I'm unable to figure out how to get started about the publishing.

I'm not looking for setting up a build server. Just want to save time publishing projects to  local folders.
Can we achieve this in a console application, by passing parameters like 'solution path' & 'target folder path', so that it can work for any such solution with multiple projects.
If not, are there any simple tools for this.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke msbuild for the solution build, you can pass

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Local /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
```

which will publish each project with the `Local` profile for you

Comment: Could you please help me how this can be done in a C# Console app